# XACML open source framework or alternative

Tags: authorization, rbac, xacml, abac, authzforce

I'm searching for a well documented XACML3-Framework in the open source world. I tried AuthZForce and AT&T XACML. Both seems to have many features. The problem: to get them running, I have to read the source code or find test-classes. There are no examples or anything else, that helps to understand the functionality of the framework. I thought XACML is the future of authorization but at the bottom there is no real community.

Is there an XACML-alternative for ABAC-implementations or is there no other way and I must use RBAC with programmed constraints?

Comment: Check out Axiomatics - where I work - we provide a fully documented authorization policy server with tutorials and video examples as well as a team  that can tackle your needs.

Comment: Thank you! I requested a demo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding AuthzForce Core (Java library), you have a tutorial on the home page of the github project: [Getting started](https://github.com/authzforce/core#getting-started); and an [example of usage with a PEP](https://github.com/authzforce/core#example-of-usage-and-pep-code-with-a-web-service-authorization-module) in a real-world scenario. If you are missing info on something, feel free to contact us on our [support mailing list](https://github.com/authzforce/core#support). I also emphasize the fact that all Java classes have Javadoc and Javadoc artifacts are published on Maven Central with every release. You can download them manually or make sure your IDE is properly set up to automatically download them when you use Maven dependencies in your Java project.

Answer (score 0):

WSO2 IS can help (opensource):

https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS510/XACML+Architecture
http://wso2.com/library/tutorials/2016/02/tutorial-how-to-enable-role-based-access-control-for-wso2-api-manager-using-xacml/

Policy handling can be done via web interface (Carbon).

Comment: But that's a complete server not a framework. I try some parts of carbon-identity-framework since yesterday, but there are also no docs.